# using the onLoad function in an iframe

Tags: javascript, xslt, iframe

I am adapting the w3shools ["XSLT on the Client"](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) tutorial to run an XSLT transform via JavaScript, but I've modified it to display results in a `div` instead of in the  tag as it is on the website. Here's their code:

```
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
```

And here's mine:

```
<div class="Tables_Wrapper">
<iframe onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</iframe>
</div>
```

My page will not render the secondary `div`. It creates the `iframe` but it is empty.

I'm quite new at this and learning on the fly - I don't really know JavaScript well so I'm simply reproducing it exactly as it appears on the w3schools website. It worked fine when I left the `body onload` tag as is, other than not appearing where I wanted it to appear on my HTML page.

Comment: Stop word-casing tag and attribute names. Keep them in lower case.

Comment: An `iframe` takes a `src` attribute pointing to the document to be rendered in it. Any markup inside the `iframe` is ignored, unless the browser does not support the `iframe` element.

Comment: So does that mean that an iframe won't support the js? I was going with iframe because this [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) page says that iframe supports the onload function.

Comment: Yes, the js function will work inside the iFrame but it needs some modifications. Are you up for it?

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction? What kinds of modifications are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a new page `Test.html` and put the div  inside it.
Then, modify the iFrame like this:

```
<iframe onload="displayResult()" id="iframeId" src="Test.html">
</iframe>​
```

Then, modify the JS like this:

```
function displayResult() {
    xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
    xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");

    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        innerDoc.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        innerDoc.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}​
```

That's it :)

Comment: Hm...still not displaying results. :(

Comment: My test page looks like this:
<html>
<body>
Sorry, your browser does not support this content.
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>

Comment: Whoops - I included the note from MCM's example before I replied to this thread. That's why that "Sorry" sentence is there. That part at least is displaying.

Comment: Not completely. I can see the plain text that I wrote in Test.html ("Sorry, your browser..."), but it's not pulling in the XML/XSLT data. After the first fail, I also changed the name of the div id on the test page from "example" to "iFrameId", and then also changed it in the js code above. Still did not present my data.

Comment: I also wanted to be sure that my test.html is supposed to be very simple, just an html and body tag, and that I'm supposed to input the div id="example" /> line (now iFrameId), and nothing else.

Comment: Ok, few things here **1**. Is the iFrame onload working? Put an alert inside `displayResult()` and test. **2**. Are the variables `iframe` & `innerDoc` equal to null? Put an alert and check. **3**. Is the `innerDoc.getElementById("example")` equal to null? Put an alert and check.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will give support for the onload event listener on an iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('iframe').load(function () {
        process();
    });
    function process() {
        alert('iframe has now loaded!'); // substitute for the code you wish to run.
    }
});
```

However, think of iframes as being like a "hole" within your webpage that you can "look through" to the external content. For this reason, HTML code within the iframe will not be rendered unless iframes are not supported (in which case you could write the user a message such as: Sorry, your browser does not support this content).

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery. Does it play well with the js from the 3schools tutorial? Would it go where Palash Mondal put the "Var iframe..." code in the answer below this one?

Comment: jQuery and raw JavaScript are compatible; jQuery is a framework that simplifies the code writing process. There are many methods that take care of common website needs, whilst being compatible with all major browsers (so you don't have to worry about it). Where my code has the line "function process() {...}", you could use your own or Palash's function. See [link](http://jquery.com) for more information.

Comment: MCM, Should I replace all of the js with the bit of JQuery that you wrote? I entered your code below the loadXMLdoc functions in the example below, and then used Palash's var irframe code after your alert line. I also left inplace Palash's loadThis command in the iframe itself. As a result I'm getting the text from the Test.html file displaying in my iframe, but not my XML/XSLT data.

Comment: I've written a fuller answer, but regrettably, I don't think iframes are suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I just don't understand why the iframe is involved here at all. If you simple want to display the contents of an XML file into a div (or *almost* any other element of your choice) of your choice, you can do so with the following code. I have used a very simple XML file for books.

**HTML**

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $.get('test.xml', function (data) {
        $('#example').html('<h1>Good Books</h1>');
        $(data).find('book').each(function () {
            var $book = $(this);
            var title = $book.attr('title');
            var html = "<br />";
            $('#example').append(title + html);
        });             
    });  
 }); 
</script>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<books>
    <book title="Hamlet">
        <description>
        info goes here.
        </description>
        </book>
        <book title="In Search of Lost Time">
        <description>
        info goes here.
        </description>
        </book>
        <book title="The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn">
        <description>
        info goes here.
        </description>
</book>
</books>
```

The above works for just about anything, other than an iframe.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I'm still not quite there. After saving the XML as a new file (text.xml), I created a new document, completely blank, placing the jquery between head tags and the HTML between body tags. This only creates a blank page. I then removed the head tags and placed both the jquery script, div, and 2nd script tag all within body tags. Still nothing. I am sure that I'm missing something completely elemental.

Comment: The XML file in my example is called _"test.xml"_, not text.xml. If that's not it, do you have the div with the id example? Also, all your files must be saved within the same folder.